# Saving and Passing String Array From JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, html, arrays, jsp, servlets

Im trying to save user input in an array and then later pass it to the servlet.I'm Stuck on What to do. I've searched and tried different codes but still no luck. I don't know if the function is wrong or in the syntax but i've tried using everything else i can think of and still stuck.

```html
<body>
  <div id="display"></div>
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form" ng-app="MyApp" layout="column" layout-sm="row" style="color: black" layout-align="center center" layout-align-sm="start start" layout-fill="">
    <md-content  class="md-whiteframe-10dp" flex-sm="">
      <md-toolbar flex="" id="materialToolbar">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <span flex=""></span>
          <span class="md-headline" align="center">Registration Form</span>
          <span flex=""></span>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
      <div layout-padding="">
        <div></div>

        <%




                                                %>
        <form action=""  >
          <input type="hidden" name="action"  />
          <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>LRN:</label>
              <input  name="a" id="lrn" required="" type="number" placeholder="Your LRN" style="width: 160px">
            </md-input-container>

            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>Student Number:</label>
              <input  name="a" id="snum" required="" type="number" placeholder="Your Student Number">
            </md-input-container>
          </div>

          <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>First Name</label>
              <input  name="a" id="fn" required="" type="text" placeholder="Your First Name">
            </md-input-container>

            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>Middle Name:</label>
              <input  name="a" id="mn" required="" type="text"  placeholder="Your Middle Name">
            </md-input-container>

            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>Last Name:</label>
              <input  name="a" id="ln" required="" type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name">
            </md-input-container>
          </div>

          <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
            <p style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 18px;">Gender: </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="a" value="{{user.gender}}"  />
            <md-radio-group style="margin: 12px 0 19px;" ng-model="user.gender" required="">
              <md-radio-button value="Male" class="md-primary">Male</md-radio-button>
              <md-radio-button value="Female" ">Female</md-radio-button>
            </md-radio-group>
          </div>
          <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
            <md-input-container flex-gt-sm="">
              <label>Parent</label>
              <input required="" type="text" id="p" name="a"  placeholder="Your Parent" />
            </md-input-container>
          </div>
          <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
            <!--<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" style="width:100%; margin: 5px 5px;" type="submit"  >Submit</md-button><br><br>

                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" style="width:100%; margin: 5px 5px;" type="reset"  >Reset</md-button><br> -->
            <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="insert();" />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="form.action='register';" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here's my function that will suppose to store the input when i press save on the arrays. but nothing happens..

```java
var LRN  = new Array();
var SNUM   =new Array();
var FN =new Array();
var MN  =new Array();
var LN   =new Array();
var G =new Array();
var P =new Array();

var lrnInput  = document.getElementById("lrn");
var snumInput   = document.getElementById("snum");
var fnInput = document.getElementById("fn");
var mnInput  = document.getElementById("mn");
var lnInput   = document.getElementById("ln");
var gInput = document.getElementById("g");
var pInput  = document.getElementById("p");

function insert ( ) {

var lrnInput  = document.getElementById("lrn").value();
var snumInput   = document.getElementById("snum").value();
var fnInput = document.getElementById("fn".value());
var mnInput  = document.getElementById("mn").value();
var lnInput   = document.getElementById("ln").value();
var gInput = document.getElementById("g").value();
var pInput  = document.getElementById("p").value();

 LRN[LRN.length]=lrnInput
 SNUM[SNUM.length]=snumInput
 FN[FN.length]=fnInput
 MN[MN.length]=mnInput
 LN[LN.length]=lnInput
 G[G.length]=gInput
 P[P.length]=pInput; 
}
```

Whenever i click the save button nothing happens .. I just tried calling lrn var but i still don't know what to do

here is my Servlet code:

```java
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

   String[] lrn = request.getParameterValues("lrn");

   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(lrn);
   try {
       out.println("<html>");
       out.println("<head>");
       out.println("<title>INFORMATION</title>");
       out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css'>");
       out.println("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style1.css'>");
       out.println("</head>");

       out.println("<body>");
       out.println("<section>");
       out.println("<h1>MALE</h1>");
       out.println("<div class='tbl-header'>");
       out.println("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>");
       out.println("<thead>");
       out.println("<tr>");
       out.println("<th>LRN</th>");
       out.println("<th>Student Number</th>");
       out.println("<th>First Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Middle Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Last Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Gender</th>");
       out.println("<th>Parent</th>");
       out.println("</tr>");
       out.println("</thead>");
       out.println("</table>");
       out.println("<div class='tbl-content'>");
       out.println("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'border='0'>");
       out.println("<tbody>");

       for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
           if (i>0 && i%7==0) {
               out.println("</tr><tr>");
           }
           out.println("<td>" + list.get(i) + "</td>");
       }
   /*
   out.println("<td>"+lrn+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+snum+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+fn+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+mn+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+ln+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+gender+"</td>");
   out.println("<td>"+parent+"</td>");*/

       out.println("</tbody>");
       out.println("</table>");
       out.println("</div>");

       out.println("</section>");

       out.println("<section>");
       out.println("<h1>FEMALE</h1>");
       out.println("<div class='tbl-header'>");
       out.println("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>");
       out.println("<thead>");
       out.println("<tr>");
       out.println("<th>LRN</th>");
       out.println("<th>Student Number</th>");
       out.println("<th>First Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Middle Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Last Name</th>");
       out.println("<th>Parent</th>");
       out.println("</tr>");
       out.println("</thead>");
       out.println("</table>");
       out.println("<div class='tbl-content'>");
       out.println("<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'border='0'>");
       out.println("<tbody>");

       out.println("</tbody>");
       out.println("</table>");
       out.println("</div>");
       out.println("</section>");
       out.println("<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>");
       out.println("<script src='js/index1.js'></script>");
       out.println("</body>");
       out.println("</html>");
   } finally {
       out.close();
   }
```

Comment: You cannot send javascript array while submitting html form. Rather you need to store them in a hidden field while calling insert() function in comma separated string and then split over there in Servlet.

Comment: @GauravSrivastav How do i suppose to do that?

Comment: Just sharing code in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Insert hidden fields for each value you want to send to servlet in jsp file.
like

```
<input type="hidden" name="lrnStr" />
```

Then in insert() function you need to write code to append each lrn value into lrnStr hidden form field.

When you submit the form then you will receive this field to and split them with comma and use.

```
function insert ( ) {
//use jquery here
   $("#lrnStr").val($("#lrnStr").val()+","+$("#lrn").val());
   //same for other fields
}
```

In servlet code you need to add following code to get list of values.

```
String lrnArray[] = null;
String lrnStr = request.getParameter("lrnStr");

if(lrnStr!=null){
 lrnArray = lrnStr.split(",");
 for (int i = 0; i<lrnArray.length; i++) {
       if (i>0 && i%7==0) {
           out.println("</tr><tr>");
       }
       out.println("<td>" + lrnArray[i] + "</td>");
 } 
}
```